# use php 5.3.3 in xampp for mac catalina (10.15.5 )

Tags: php, macos, operating-system

I have xampp on my mac catalina 10.15.5  and it has php 7, I need to downgrade it to php 5.3.3, is there a way for it, or is there a xampp version that could work on mac 10.15.5?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, there are many virtual servers that  include multiple versions of PHP and can control it on the go! So if it's possible try to change your web server.